# Is the pooled variance equal to the variance of the centered populations?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, pooling

Suppose two data arrays of length $n$ with variance $\sigma^2$ and mean $\mu$.

Is the pooled variance $\sigma_P^2 = \frac{(n_1-1)\sigma_1^2 + (n_2-1)\sigma_2^2}{(n_1-1) + (n_2-1)}$ equal to the variance of the centered concatenated data $ \textrm{Var}(x_{1,1}-\mu_1, ..., x_{1,n_1}-\mu_1,\,x_{2,1}-\mu_2, ..., x_{2,n_2}-\mu_2)$?

I've tested this in python as follows:

```py
import math
from random import gauss
import numpy as np

var1 = 3
var2 = 10

mean1 = 3
mean2 = 50

n1 = 500
n2 = 1000

x1 = [gauss(mean1, math.sqrt(var1)) for i in range(n1)]
x2 = [gauss(mean2, math.sqrt(var2)) for i in range(n2)]

pooled = ((len(x1)-1)*np.var(x1, ddof=1) + (len(x2)-1)*np.var(x2, ddof=1)) / ((len(x1)-1) + (len(x2)-1)) # 7.007545276099887 

concd = np.var(np.concatenate((x1-np.mean(x1), x2-np.mean(x2)))) # 6.998201882398422
```

For both approaches the variance is approximately 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you estimate the concatenated variance with degrees of freedom equals to $2$:

```
np.var(np.concatenate((x1-np.mean(x1), x2-np.mean(x2))), ddof=2)
```

Because, $(n_i-1)S_i^2=\sum_{n=1}^{n_i} (x_{i,n}-\hat\mu_i)^2$ and when summed over $i$, this is going to be equal to the *unnormalized* variance of the concatenated array. And you need to normalize it with $n_1+n_2-2$.